# Custom PRISM ribbon region adaptor with navigation support

Tags: wpf, prism, desktop-application

I am using a [region adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.composite.regions.iregionadapter.aspx) for the ribbon control which i have found in this article [Creating View-Switching Application with PRISM 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165370/Creating-View-Switching-Applications-with-Prism-4). All my ribbon tabs are defined in separate modules with a distinct view model bound to each tab's data context. All my view models implement [INavigationAware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.inavigationaware%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) but non the less, not a single method of this interface is called by PRISM, what could be the problem and how to solve it ?
**NOTE**: i tried to implment IActiveAware on the tab controls to see if they are being activated but they are not or the interface's methods aren't getting called too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution this this problem using Region Behaviors.